# .h file not found in the library inside the Pods folder

Tags: swift, cocoapods

When I build the app I get this error
`'GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults/Public/GoogleUtilities/GULUserDefaults.h' file not found"`
in the GULUserDefaults.
When I open any .m file in Pods forder the error will also appear corresponding to the first `#import ...` line

First I tried the following:

> Delete podfile.lock
> Delete Derived data
> Delete .xcworkspace
> Delete Pods folder
> Run pod install
> Clean build folder
> Build

-> It can't be

Then I tried with other ways:

> Update to the latest CocoaPods 1.11.2
> Update to MacOS 12.0.1
> Update to XCode 13.1
> Clean cache - [pod cache clean --all]

I asked a colleague to send me the source code, including the Pods, which built successfully. But my computer still won't work.

I don't know what else to do to overcome this problem, hope everyone can help me.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?